# Handling Whitespace in the Regexp::Grammars Module

Tags: regex, perl, parsing

I have a grammar that I'm trying to parse with the help of Regexp::Grammars but for some reason it looks like it's having a whitespace problem.  I've managed to reduce it to the following:

```
use Modern::Perl;
use v5.16;

use Regexp::Grammars;
use Data::Dumper;

my $grammar = qr{ 
    <foo> <baz> | my <foo> is <baz>

    <rule: foo> foo | fu | phoo
    <rule: baz> bazz?
}ix;

while (<>) {
    chomp;

    if (/$grammar/) {
        say Dumper(\%/);
    }
    else {
        say "NO MATCH!!\n";
    }

}
```

When the program is run and any matching sequence such as

```
foo baz
phoo bazz
my fu is baz
```

is entered the program returns

```
NO MATCH!!
```

However, if I insert a debugging directive before the grammar definition:

```
<debug: match>
<foo> <baz> | my <foo> is <baz>
...
```

I get what I expect:

```
perl.exe : ========> Trying <grammar> from position 0
At line:1 char:5
+ perl <<<<  .\test_grammar2.pl 2>&1 > output.txt
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (========> Tryin...from position 0:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

phoo bazz |...Trying <foo>    

          |   |...Trying subpattern /foo/    
          |   |    \FAIL subpattern /foo/
          |   |...Trying next alternative    
          |   |...Trying subpattern /fu/    
          |   |    \FAIL subpattern /fu/
          |   |...Trying next alternative    
          |   |...Trying subpattern /phoo/    
 bazz     |   |    \_____subpattern /phoo/ matched 'phoo'    
          |    \_____<foo> matched 'phoo'    
          |...Trying <baz>    
          |   |...Trying subpattern /bazz?/    
[eos]     |   |    \_____subpattern /bazz?/ matched 'bazz'    
          |    \_____<baz> matched ' bazz'    
           \_____<grammar> matched 'phoo bazz' 

$VAR1 = {
          '' => 'phoo baz',
          baz => ' bazz',
          foo => 'phoo'
        };
```

Similarly, if I put an optional whitespace sequence between the subrule and literal calls:

```
<foo>\s*<baz> ...
...
```

I also get a match.

I'm using Winodws 7, ActivePerl Build 1603, Perl 5.16.3 and PowerShell.  I've tried using cmd.exe as well just in case there was some obscure PowerShell issue but I have the same problem.  I've also tried matching directly:

```
my $s = q(fu baz);
if ($s =~ $grammar) {
    ...
}
```

but I get the same problem--with the same solution.

EDIT: What I've learned.

When using the Regexp::Grammars module, if your grammar requires spaces between literals, subrules or both then you need to either encapsulate:

```
<foobaz>

<rule: foobaz> <foo> <baz> | my <foo> is <baz>
```

escape:

```
<foo>\ <baz> | my\ <foo>\ is\ <baz>
```

or insert whitespace sequences:

```
<foo>\s+<baz> | my\s+<foo>\s+is\s+<baz>
```

Comment: Message after installing `Regexp::Grammers` - `We deeply regret that Regexp::Grammars cannot currently be maintained completely due to these backwards-incompatible changes and bugs in Perl 5.18.`.  Apparently my Strawberry perl 5.18.2 won't work with that module.

Comment: If I had better internet right now I'd download Stawberry Perl and see if it's an ActivePerl problem.

Comment: I have not yet tested this module, but since you use the x modifier, I think that your pattern is seen as `<foo><baz>|my<foo>is<baz>` (since the whitespaces are ignored). Try to put a literal space inside a character class `[ ]` instead of using `\s*`.

Comment: The `x` modifier treats whitespace in the expression as _ignorable_ not ignored.  Moreover, the Regexp::Grammars modules implicitly matches whitespace using the `<.ws>` token which is defined as `\s*` by default.

Comment: From the doc:`"[The start-]pattern is treated like a token for whitespace matching behaviour"`. However this doesn't explain why you obtain a match in debug mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I figured out what the issue was.  The top level match in a Regexp::Grammars expression is treated in token mode (whitespace not ignored) rather than in rule mode (whitespace ignored).  So, to get what you want, you only need to add a top rule:

```
my $grammar = qr{
    <top>

    <rule: top>     <foo> <baz> |
                    my <foo> is <baz>
    <rule: foo> foo | fu | phoo
    <rule: baz> bazz?
}ix;
```

Here's my complete program:

```
use Modern::Perl;
use v5.16;

use Regexp::Grammars;
use Data::Dumper;

my $grammar = qr{
    <top>

    <rule: top>     <foo> <baz> |
                    my <foo> is <baz>
    <rule: foo> foo | fu | phoo
    <rule: baz> bazz?
}ix;

1;
while (<>) {
    chomp;

    if (/$grammar/) {
        say Dumper(\%/);
    }
    else {
        say "NO MATCH!!\n";
    }

}
```

Here's my output:

```
% echo FU baz | perl grammar.pl
$VAR1 = {
          '' => 'FU baz',
          'top' => {
                     '' => 'FU baz',
                     'baz' => 'baz',
                     'foo' => 'FU'
                   }
        };

% echo my phoo is bazz | perl grammar.pl
$VAR1 = {
          '' => 'my phoo is bazz',
          'top' => {
                     '' => 'my phoo is bazz',
                     'baz' => 'bazz',
                     'foo' => 'phoo'
                   }
        };
```

The documentation for Regexp::Grammars specifically states that the top level is done in token mode.  Adding a top level token only adds one layer to the parse tree, but I don't think you have a choice if whitespace is to be ignored at the top level.

Comment: Thanks for trying Mark but I'm not getting the exhibited behaviour because the module treats the invocation of the base rule as a token.  Tokens are simply treated as normal regex patterns so the spaces should have no bearing on my problem as I'm using the `x` modifier. The real grammar is expansive and I don't want to have to deal with extra key layers when trying to extract my data let alone making modifications to the grammar. I think you were on the right track with your original answer.  My guess right now is that it's an ActiveState or Windows implementation issue.

Comment: I'm afraid that I don't see what the issue is with my solution.  All you need to do is insert a start token (I've called it "top" above) that expands as a rule, and then your entire top-level grammar becomes the rewrite section of that token.  You won't need to make any other modifications to the grammar, and when you are done, you just need to strip away the 'top' part of the data structure.  You can even encapsulate that part if you want to hide it from any users.

Comment: The issue I had is that it looked like a hack and defeated part of the point of using the module. I realize now that I've been misconstruing the use of the `x` modifier.  So that and the fact that it worked using a `<debug: ...>` directive threw me off.

Comment: Thanks for bringing this very interesting package to my attention.  I'm tempted to start using it except for the message from @Miller that it is not supported in 5.18 (at least yet).